# Oracle APEX 20.1: Theme Vita Dark CSS-Error on Textfield with autocomplete

Tags: apex, darkmode

When you apply the Vita Dark-theme to your app and have selection lists, such as in a textfield with autocomplete, the background and the text in the select list are white and thus hard to read.

[Screenshot to show the wrong colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZYG0.png)

Is there any workaround to this? All the other standard themes work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be addressed with a snippet of css which can be easily added in theme roller under custom css for Vita - Dark theme.

```
    .oj-listbox-drop { 
        background-color: #222629; 
        color: #fefefe; 
        border-width: 0; 
        border-radius: 2px; 
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); 
        padding: 8px 0 
    } 

    .oj-inputsearch-choice { 
        color: inherit; 
        background-color: transparent; 
        border-color: transparent 
    } 

   .oj-listbox-results .oj-hover { 
        --oj-listbox-bg-color-hover: #0076df; 
        background-color: #0076df; 
        color: #fff 
   }
```